# Azure Function binding issue for BlobInput without any error

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions

I have created in VSCode an azure function in Java that works well locally.

```
@FunctionName("HttpTriggerGetSha256")
    @StorageAccount("AzureWebJobsStorage")
    public HttpResponseMessage run (
        @HttpTrigger(
            name = "req", 
            methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST}, 
            authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) 
        HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
        @BlobInput(
            name = "source", 
            dataType = "binary", 
            path = "{Query.directory}/{Query.filename}")  
        byte[] content,
        final ExecutionContext context) {
        context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");
...
}
```

The input binding is ok, "content" is filled with the content of the filename.

When I deploy to azure, the function fails. The "content" is null which means that there is 2 possible cause:

- path is not correctly filled and created with the Query
- it is impossible to open or access the blob
  I have hardcoded the "path" to make a test but I don't see any content filled too!

AzureWebJobsStorage is correctly filled.

Any tips or something I have to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After deploying to `Azure portal`, the value of `AzureWebJobsStorage` is the connection string of the storage where this `Azure function` is located.

Here you can check if the value of `AzureWebJobsStorage` is the connection string of the storage you want to specify.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, indeed, I've just check and change the code to @StorageAccount("Storage_Account_Connection_String"), add it to the app configuration but I still have the same problem.